# Attempt to index nil to 'Takedamage'

Tags: roblox

The thing is that I'm making a combat system, and there is the situation with line 56 that says: enemyHumanoid:TakeDamage(Damage) and the error says:  ServerScriptService.CombatSystem:56: attempt to index nil with 'TakeDamage' and I don't know what to do (also this is the entire code)

```
local rp = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Combat = rp:WaitForChild("Combat")

local Debris = game:GetService("Debris")

local Animations = script:WaitForChild("Animations")
local Meshes = script:WaitForChild("Meshes")

local anims = 
    {
        Animations:WaitForChild("Right"),
        Animations:WaitForChild("Left"),
        Animations:WaitForChild("Gut"),
        Animations:WaitForChild("Kick"),
    }

local limbs = 
    {
        "RightHand",
        "LeftHand",
        "RightHand",
        "RightFoot"
    }

local Damage = 10
Combat.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,count)
    local Character = player.Character
    local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    
    local attack = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(anims[count])
    attack:Play()
    
    local Limb = Character:WaitForChild(limbs[count])
    
    local folder = Instance.new("Folder",Character)
    folder.Name = player.Name.."Melee"
    
    local Hitbox = Meshes:WaitForChild("Hitbox"):Clone()
    Hitbox.CFrame = Limb.CFrame
    Hitbox.Parent = folder
    Debris:AddItem(Hitbox,.5)
    
    local weld = Instance.new("ManualWeld")
    weld.Part0 = Hitbox
    weld.Part1 = Limb
    weld.C0 = weld.Part0.CFrame:ToObjectSpace(weld.Part1.CFrame)
    weld.Parent = weld.Part0
    
    Hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
        if Hit:IsA("BasePart") then
            if not Hit:IsDescendantOf(Character) then
                local enemyHumanoid = Hitbox.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
                if Humanoid then
                    Hitbox:Destroy()
                        
                    enemyHumanoid:TakeDamage(Damage)
                    
                end
            end
        end
    end)
        
    Combat:FireClient(player)
end)
```

I haven't try a lot but it keeps getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

`:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")` returns nil if the Humanoid doesn't exist, which is why `enemyHumanoid:TakeDamage()` isn't working. Try using this snippet in place of the current Hitbox.Touched function:

```lua
Hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
    if Hit:IsA("BasePart") and not Hit:IsDescendantOf(Character) then
        local enemyHumanoid = Hitbox.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
        if Humanoid then
            Hitbox:Destroy()

            if enemyHumanoid then -- Make sure enemyHumanoid exists and isn't nil
                enemyHumanoid:TakeDamage(Damage)
            end
        end
    end
end)
```